# How to add an entity without related entities, but saving relation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, change-tracking

As far as I understand, if I change a state of an entry in context like that:

```
context.Entry(doc).State = EntityState.Added;
```

the whole object graph behind `doc` will be set to `EntityState.Added`. That is how this mechanism described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx):

> Note that for all of these examples if the entity being added has
>   references to other entities that are not yet tracked then these new
>   entities will also be added to the context and will be inserted into
>   the database the next time that SaveChanges is called.

In my situation this behaviour is undesirable. When I receive `doc` entity, it's relations are already in database (were added in different context) and adding them again will cause an error. I need to add `doc` to a database with all references, but don't try to add other objects in graph.

Of course, I can iterate through all graph and set state explicitly, but does an easier way exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Entity Framework **Core***, the behavior changed, calling:

```
context.Entry(asset).State = EntityState.Added;
```

will affect only the entity and not the related ones.

[image]

I know the question is for Entity Framework *classic* (not *Core*), but surely will be more people using **EF Core** reaching here (like me)

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff)

According to this [dedicated blog entry](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/), it seems to fit your needs :

> Say you have a Company which has many Contacts. A contact is not
>   defined on its own and is a One-To-Many (with required parent) record
>   of a Company. i.e. The company is the Aggregate Root. Assume you have
>   a detached Company graph with its Contacts attached and want to
>   reflect the state of this graph in the database.
>
> At present using the Entity Framework you will need to perform the
>   updates of the contacts manually, check if each contact is new and
>   add, check if updated and edit, check if removed then delete it from
>   the database. Once you have to do this for a few different aggregates
>   in a large system you start to realize there must be a better, more
>   generic way.
>
> Well good news is that after a few refactorings I've found a nice solution to this problem.